# Lost Gestures iPad landscape

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uigesturerecognizer, uisplitviewcontroller

I have an app with an `MGSplitView` containing a table view and a `UIWebView`, which is fixed to landscape.  The web view has a `UITapGestureRecognizer` (for a triple tap) attached to the web view.  Taps in the left portion of the web view work; taps on the right side of the web view are lost - the action is not triggered, and the gesture delegate messages are not received.

The problem seems not to lie in the `MGSplitViewController`, as switching to a `UISplitViewController` has the same issues; changing from a tap to a long press also has the same results.

Tap locations are reported with the x coordinate at or close to the max width of the gesture.view, and yet are clearly made close to the centre of the display, which I expect has something to do with the root of the problem - and yet the web view contents are clearly visible and correctly placed.

All the view controllers involved implement `shouldAutorotate` and `supportedInterfaceOrientations`, so being stuck in portrait seems unlikely i.e. `MGSplitViewController`, my `UITableView` subclass (left hand panel) and `UIViewController` subclass for the right hand panel.

My gesture recognizer delegate and output from one triple-tap (the view in the right hand panel web view):

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    NSLog(@"gestureRecognizer view frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(gestureRecognizer.view.frame));
    NSLog(@"location %@", NSStringFromCGPoint([gestureRecognizer locationInView:gestureRecognizer.view]));
    return YES;
}

-[DocumentBrowser gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:]
gestureRecognizer view frame: {{0, 0}, {703, 704}}
location {703, -20}
-[DocumentBrowser gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:]
gestureRecognizer view frame: {{0, 0}, {703, 704}}
location {414.5, 204.5}
-[DocumentBrowser gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:]
gestureRecognizer view frame: {{0, 0}, {703, 704}}
location {414.5, 204.5}
```

The first location reported seems strange.

Comment: The misbehaving view is/was a UIViewControllerWrapperView, the superview of my view controller's view.  It seems more than a little unreasonable that an Apple-private class should be responsible for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your orientation and view resizing mechanisms.  I've seen this several times when something is wrong in these areas - if you log the touch locations, I think you will probably find that they stop at 768 points from the left-hand side, i.e. there is a view somewhere that thinks it is in portrait orientation.

Comment: I have seen touch coords at x = 1024 (although this is still approx 730 from left side of screen).  I will re-check the orientations, as this seems plausible.

Comment: All the view controllers involved implement shouldAutorotate and supportedInterfaceOrientations, so being stuck in portrait seems unlikely.

Comment: Problem was tracked down to a superview that wasn't resized - as it also wasn't clipping, the 'top' view was visible at full width, but the gestures were lost.